# Control dimension of vector at run time

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am working on a program that needs to be able to create vectors with different dimensions at runtime. I know that C++ templates are a compile time feature, and I am not sure how to work around this currently. I have seen some examples that use if statements to control the allocation of memory like so:

```
    if (some_condition == 1) {
        std::vector<int> x;
    } else if (some_condition == 2) {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> x;
    } // repeat for how ever many times
```

This works fine as a temporary solution, but I would really like there to be a way to control the dimension of a created vector without brute forcing if else statements up to some arbitrary number. If it is not possible would it be possible to make my own vector class, but with fixed types? I have tried making a 1 dimensional vector and using math to index it like a multi dimensional vector, but this seems to get complicated fast.

```
template<typename class_name>
class rvector
{
    std::vector<class_name> items;
    int depth;
    // Some collection type that lays out the format of all the items

}
```

Comment: If the possible number of dimensions is small (i.e., only 1, 2, or 3 dimensions) it might be possible to come up with some template weirdness. Otherwise you'll have to implement your own template that does something like this. There's nothing in the C++ library that works like this.

Comment: *I am working on a program that needs to be able* -- Unless we know what this program's goal is, it is an opinion if it "needs to be able" to create run-time multidimensional vectors.  I bet that whatever problem your program is supposed to solve, it has been done without the need to create arbitrary multidimensional arrays at runtime.

Comment: You can use a `std::unordered_map<std::vector<int>, int>` where the vector contains the indexes. The map doesn't care how many indexes you have in the vector so you can pick whatever at runtime.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow This is great, I think that in my question I should have explained how I want to represent a poly-dimensional vector at runtime, and for this a map works great after I throw some setters around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to implement the recursive template application:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct ID {};

template<size_t i, typename U>
auto n_dim_vec_gen(U u)
{
    if constexpr (i) {
        return n_dim_vec_gen<i - 1>(std::vector<U>());
    } else {
        return u;
    }
}

template<typename T, size_t i>
using n_dim_vec = decltype(n_dim_vec_gen<i>(std::declval<T>()));

static_assert(std::is_same<n_dim_vec<int, 1>, std::vector<int>>::value);
static_assert(std::is_same<n_dim_vec<int, 2>, std::vector<std::vector<int>>>::value);
```

If you'd also like to standardize the `some_condition` processing, then you need to make a runtime - to - compile-time bridge (a simple switch statement works) and then apply the lambda. You *might* generate the branches of the switch using e.g. `BOOST_PP_FOREACH`, but that might be a little overkill. Then apply the pre-defined lambda.

```
auto whatToDo = [&](auto x, auto depth) {
    // note that depth's type is compile-time
    // integral_constant, so you can use it in e.g.
    // if constexpr and template arguments
    
    n_dim_vec<int, depth> x;
    // ...
};

// this is the runtime - to - compile-time bridge
switch (some_condition) {
#define CASE(I) case I: whatToDo(std::integral_constant<int, I>()); break;
    CASE(1)
    CASE(2)
    CASE(3)
    // ...
#undef CASE
};
```

Comment: Most sources all suggest a similar process to what you have here, so I'm guessing what I am trying to do is not very feasible.  This works fine, I guess I will just pick a number that you can't go over, thinking 3 or 4 dimensions.